# Does Windows Installer use Assembly Version or File Version to update dlls

Tags: .net-2.0, windows-installer, versioning, isolatedstorage

I have a .net (2.0) winforms application that I need to upgrade on client machines. At the moment this is done by incrementing the Assembly Version and File Version on all of the projects and incrementing the version on the Installer project in VS2008.

The application now makes use of Isolated Storage to save some user settings in an XML file (grid layouts etc...).

The problem I am now facing is that if I increment all the version numbers, the application *has a new location for its **Isolated Storage***, because the ***File Version*** has changed. With a new location for isolated storage, all the settings have effectively been lost.

When upgrading does Windows installer replace the dlls based on the **File Version** or the **Assembly Version**?

If it is the Assembly Version then all I'd have to do is not increment the File Version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good reading and discussion here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/6ed4d384-f6e9-42ee-b485-0bf40d0abd65/

To answer your question, though, I believe that MSI's respect FileVersion primarily:

[File Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599(VS.85).aspx)